# Image corners not touching each other when they should

Tags: css

I have a layout with an image on the left or right with the text next to it on the opposite side that when it stacks on mobile the text is always on the top.

For some reason unless the page is in Quirks mode the images don't touch each in the corners even though they should. The DIV ends up slightly taller than the image and I can't figure out why this is.

```css
.site-feature-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: row;
    text-align: center;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.site-feature-image-section {
    width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { 
.site-feature-image-section {
    width: 100%;
}
}
    
.site-feature-info-section {
    width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { 
.site-feature-info-section{
    width: 100%;
}
}

.dmwp-work-content:nth-child(even){
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
    
.site-feature-container:nth-child(even){
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.site-feature-container {
    flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
}
}

.site-feature-image {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.site-feature-description {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="site-feature-container">
   <div class="site-feature-image-section">
      <div class="site-feature-image">
         <img class="site-feature-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-feature-info-section">
      <div class="site-feature-description">
         <p>TITLE</p>
         <p>DESC</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="site-feature-container">
   <div class="site-feature-image-section">
      <div class="site-feature-image">
         <img class="site-feature-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-feature-info-section">
      <div class="site-feature-description">
         <p>TITLE</p>
         <p>DESC</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

It seems like it should be a relatively easy fix but I'm not too sure what exactly in the CSS is causing it, removing the Doctype declaration fixes it but obviously the page needs that.

[image: Example of the corners not touching]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: either display:block to the image or vertical-align:top .. the line-height is a hacky solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the famous problem of inline elements.

One way is to force the line-height to null :

```
.site-feature-image-section {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Another way but that make your html less readable is to avoid spaces in your code between two following inline elements, like :

```
</div><div class="site-feature-info-section">
```

Comment: That's solved it, I don't know why this only happens outside of quirks mode. Thanks for the solve though, I'll accept when SO allows me to.

Comment: Sorry I'm not mean to disrespect your answer, just when i was posting my answer your answer was not loaded. if you want me to delte my answer, i will

Comment: @Gad No problem at all, we are here for sharing :)

Comment: @iguypouf thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your image has space under it which is reserved for descender text elements. The easiest way to get rid of it is to set the vertical-align property to something other than the default of baseline. For example, `vertical-align:top` on the image:

```css
.site-feature-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: row;
    text-align: center;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.site-feature-image-section {
    width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { 
.site-feature-image-section {
    width: 100%;
}
}
    
.site-feature-info-section {
    width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { 
.site-feature-info-section{
    width: 100%;
}
}

.dmwp-work-content:nth-child(even){
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
    
.site-feature-container:nth-child(even){
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.site-feature-container {
    flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
}
}

.site-feature-image {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.site-feature-description {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="site-feature-container">
   <div class="site-feature-image-section">
      <div class="site-feature-image">
         <img class="site-feature-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-feature-info-section">
      <div class="site-feature-description">
         <p>TITLE</p>
         <p>DESC</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="site-feature-container">
   <div class="site-feature-image-section">
      <div class="site-feature-image">
         <img class="site-feature-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080" alt="">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="site-feature-info-section">
      <div class="site-feature-description">
         <p>TITLE</p>
         <p>DESC</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

That also works:

```
.site-feature-image {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```